# How do I deactivate a broken iphone 4s and switch to an old iphone 4s a friend gave me?

Tags: iphone

I recently broke my iPhone 4s and am not due for an update for another year. My friend is going to let me use her old iPhone 4s. How do I deactivate my broken phone so that my friends phone will now be usable as mine? My carrier is Verizon

Comment: The so friendly ppl at Verizon can do that free of charge for you. Not sure about the free of charge so some negotiating skills might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can call Verizon customer support @ 1 (800) 922-0204. They should be able to deactivate your phone and activate the replacement. Even in the case of newer phones that are unlocked like the iPhone 6 - you still need a Verizon rep to activate the device after placing the SIM in it due to how their network is configured.

Answer (score 0):

I simply put the old sim card into the "new" phone to immediately have phone access. I plan to call ATT and have the new phone officially activated.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your device in DFU mode then do a full iTunes restore. If not fixed then vist the apple store or call Verizon Support.

Comment: Please include information as to how to do that.